# Merge data in Stata by creating new variables

Tags: stata

I have two sets of data below in Stata

| name |
| --- |
| a |
| b |

| name | case # | content |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | o |
| a | 2 | p |
| a | 3 | q |
| b | 1 | r |
| b | 2 | s |

How do I turn them into:

| name | 1st case | 2nd case | 3rd case |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | o | p | q |
| b | r | s |  |

Comment: It looks like you've already done it. Is this related to a specific programming language or data format (e.g. JSON)? If so, please update the question to reflect those details.

Comment: stata in the title?

Comment: A good question should show _some_ attempt at code.

Answer (score 1):

```
clear

input str1(name) case str1(content)
a 1 o
a 2 p
a 3 q
b 1 r
b 2 s
end

reshape wide content, i(name) j(case)

list, noobs

  +---------------------------------------+
  | name   content1   content2   content3 |
  |---------------------------------------|
  |    a          o          p          q |
  |    b          r          s            |
  +---------------------------------------+
```